# Getting strange errors while downloading mysql

Tags: server, mysql, downloads

I'm trying to install mysql to my new laptop and I'm getting these funny errors.

```
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Cannot stat file /proc/2801/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2812/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2816/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/7: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/8: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/9: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/10: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/11: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/12: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/56: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/57: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2846/fd/1023: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2861/fd/6: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2861/fd/7: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2861/fd/8: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2861/fd/9: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2861/fd/10: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2861/fd/11: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2873/fd/4: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2873/fd/6: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2873/fd/7: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2873/fd/8: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/6: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/7: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/8: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/9: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/10: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/11: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/15: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/2879/fd/16: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled mysql about 4 times, and the same thing happens. I have another lamp stack running fine on my older server, any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Need more information. @Ryan Akuszewski, your question displays a long list of `Permission denied`. What was the command you gave to get such a long list? Please reproduce first the command you gave and then responses you received and then post it!

Comment: @Marmayogi I received this when I tried to download mysql using sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: Are you installed with Ubuntu 18.04? are you installing MySQL 8.0.13 Server on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I am installing MySQL 8.0.13 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This worked for me https://mlog.club/article/2247728 . I was running Linux ulyssa

Answer (score 6):

> My observation was that error **"Cannot stat file /proc/2801/fd/1023: Permission denied"** which I never faced before, probably need @Ryan Akuszewski laptop for further analysis. I am suprised with the error **"installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit"** because @Ryan Akuszewski was installing `MYSQL 8.0.13 server` however there was a reference to `"mysql-server-5.7 package"` which was odd. The problem should be with dependencies, so the laptop requires to sort them out before proceeding to install. That is why I began the process with dependency installation.
>
> If any one has better insight into this issue, please come out and share their expert opinion.

You may need to install the `libaio` library if it is not already present on your system:

**how to check if libaio is installed (quickly)**

`$ apt-cache policy libaio1`

If it's installed, it will display the version installed, if it's not, it will display the lines of text. If it is installed then skip Install libaio and goto step-1.

**Install libaio**

`$ sudo apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev`

**Note**: use the following commands in order to fix all the dependencies for `libaio1`, `libmecab2` and so on.

```
$ sudo aptitude update 
$ sudo aptitude upgrade
```

**Note**: Make sure that `aptitude` has been installed in Ubuntu.

[image]
`Figure-1: Install libaio1`

**Step 1 Get MySQL APT Repository**

The MySQL package version that comes with Ubuntu default repositories is not the latest version. If you need to install the latest version of MySQL database, you may want to install its repository in Ubuntu.
You can also use the command line to download, changing the version number of the package.

`$ cd /tmp/ && wget` https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb

Then run the commands below to install

`$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb`

When you run the commands above, you should get a config prompt. Just select OK as shown in the image below.

MySQL APT Repo features MySQL Server along with a variety of MySQL components. You may select the appropriate product to choose the version that you wish to receive.

**Step 2: Install MySQL 8.0.13 Server and Client.**

Now that the repository is installed, run the commands below to install

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

There are also packages with `server-core` and `client-core` in the package names. These
contain binaries only and are installed automatically by the standard packages. Installing them by themselves will not result in a functioning MySQL setup.

If you are being warned of unmet dependencies by `dpkg`, you can fix them using `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install   # Fix/correct the system with any broken dependencies in place.
$ cd ~
```

Here are where the files are installed on the system:

- All configuration files (like `my.cnf`) are under `/etc/mysql`
- All binaries, libraries, headers, etc., are under `/usr/bin` and
  `/usr/sbin`
- The data directory is under `/var/lib/mysql`

**Warning:** Debian distributions of MySQL are also provided by other vendors. Be aware that they may differ from those built by Oracle in features, capabilities, and conventions (including communication setup), and that the instructions in this manual do not necessarily apply to installing them. The vendor's instructions should be consulted instead.

When you run the commands above, you should get a config prompt. Just select OK as shown in the image below. But unfortunately, my observation was, MySQL was not supporting `Cosmic Cuttlefish` (Ubuntu 18.10), the installation was trying to abort, but you can select `Ubuntu Bionic` (18.04) and go ahead with installation. Use Up arrow and select `ubuntu bionic` (18.04) as shown in figure-1.

**Navigational Tips:**

a) Use <kbd>↑</kbd>or<kbd>↓</kbd> to position the cursor on your choice of System.
b) Hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to mark your selection (Don't ignore this step).
c) Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to `OK` button and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

[image]
`Figure-2: Select ubuntu bionic (18.04) in the absence of ubuntu cosmic (18.10)`

MySQL APT Repo features MySQL Server along with a variety of MySQL components. You may select the appropriate product to choose the version that you wish to receive.

[image]
`Figure-3: Select appropriate product`

During the installation, you should be prompted to create and confirm a MySQL root password.

[image]
`Figure-4: Enter password`

[image]
`Figure-5: Re-Enter password`

Also, you confirm whether you want to use the new password encryption feature. it’s recommended.

[image]
`Figure-6: password encryption feature`

[image]
`Figure-7: Configuring mysql communuty server`

Special Notes on Upgrading the Shared Client Libraries

- You can install the shared client libraries from MySQL APT repository
  by the following command (see [Installing Additional MySQL Products
  and Components with APT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html#apt-repo-install-components) for more details):`shell> sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient20`
- If you already have the shared client libraries installed from you
  Linux platform's software repository, it can be updated by the MySQL
  APT repository with its own package by using the same command (see
  [Replacing the Native Distribution by an APT Update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html#repo-qg-apt-replace-native) for more
  details).
- After updating MySQL using the APT repository, applications compiled
  with older versions of the shared client libraries should continue to
  work.

To install the shared client libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18
```

[image]
`Figure-8: install the shared client libraries`

The MySQL services should start automatically after installation, check its status to ensure that it is up and running.

`$ sudo service mysql status`

After that, MySQL should be installed, you can logon by running the commands:

`$ sudo mysql -u root -p`

You should see MySQL welcome screen shown below:

[image]
`Figure-9: Login into mysql`

**Step 3: Verify the MySQL Installation**

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql    # Show packages relating to mysql
```

[image]
`Figure-10: Show packages relating to mysql`

Thus the list of packages is shown in the above figure-10.

```
$ dpkg --status mysql-server            # Check the details of a package
```

[image]
`Figure-11: Status of mysql server`

The status of server is shown in the above figure-11.

```
$ dpkg --listfiles mysql-server     # List the installed files of a package
```

[image]
`Figure-12: List the installed files of the package`

The following commands will check the location of `"mysqld"` (MySQL server deamon):

`$ which mysqld`

[image]
`Figure-13: Location of mysql server deamon`

`$ whereis mysqld`
[image]
`Figure-14: Where is msqld?`

As seen from the above output, the MySQL server daemon `mysqld` is installed at `/usr/sbin` (System-Software Binaries).

`$ man mysqld   // Read the manual`
[image]
`Figure-15: Read the manual for MySQL server daemon`

The following commands will check the location of "mysql" (MySQL command-line client)

`$ which mysql`

[image]
`Figure-16: Mysql is installed in '/usr/bin'`

`$ whereis mysql`

[image]
`Figure-17: Mysql related directories`

As seen from the above output, the MySQL command-line client `mysql` and utilities such as `mysqladmin` and `mysqldump` are located at `/usr/bin` (Application Software Binaries).

`$ man mysql   // Read the manual`

[image]
`Figure-18: Read the manual for MySQL Command line tool`

**Step 4: Configure MySQL Server**

MySQL reads the startup options from the files shown below, in the specified order (top files are read first, files read later take precedence. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html)

1. `/etc/my.cnf`
2. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
3. `SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf`
4. `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf (server only)`
5. The file specified in `--defaults-extra-file` startup option, if any
6. `~/.my.cnf`
7. `~/.mylogin.cnf` (client only)

The installation default `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` includes directories `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` and `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/.` The `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` is empty. Hence, the main configuration file is `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

Browse through `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
......
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
......
```

- A special user called `"mysql"` is created to run the MySQL server.
- The server runs on the default port number of `3306`.
- The data directory is located at `/var/lib/mysql` (owned by
  `mysql:mysql`).
- The error log is located at `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

**Step 5: Start/Shutdown MySQL Server (`mysqld`)**

MySQL is run as a service called `"mysql"` (configured at `"/etc/init.d/mysql"`), which is started automatically after boot. To start/stop/restart mysql, you could:

```
$ sudo service mysql start
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo service mysql restart        # Stop and start
$ sudo service mysql status         # Show the status
```

MySQL server will be started automatically after the installation. You CANNOT start another instance! To check the `mysqld` process:

`$ ps aux | grep mysqld`

[image]
`Figure-18: mysqld instance has begun`

**Step 6: Start/Stop MySQL Command-line Client (`mysql`)**

To start a MySQL client:

```
$ mysql -u root -p          # Enter the password for the root user you have set in Step 1

mysql> select user, host, authentication_string from mysql.user;
```

[image]
`Figure-20: Host and Authentication_string information for various users`

`mysql> exit`

**Step 7: Check Status of MySQL.**

```
$ sudo service mysql status     # Show the status
```

[image]
`Figure-21: Status information of Mysql Server Process.`

That how to install the latest version of MySQL on Ubuntu! Enjoy!!

Comment: 1+ Well written answer, but I think this answer more suitable for `How do I install latest mysql`, and not `Getting strange errors while downloading mysql`.

Comment: @Emmet I think there's [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122608/) already in existence.

Comment: I know, what I mean is... kinda strange to post detailed instruction regarding MySQL installation, while the question about `How do I fix error when download mysql`. Yes, it is related, maybe reinstallation can fix the broken package, but the he did not address the OP original issue.

Comment: well I get the same error in Docker with 18.04 , mysql 5.7 and newer ... mysql silent install used to be a one-liner ... and now is basically 2 A4 of BROKEN scripts ... thanks Oracle for spending 1 Billion to buy out your competition and slowly destroy it on purpose ...