# 20.04.1 frequent freezes, hangs, or lockups?

Tags: freeze, lockup

A few weeks ago I clean installed 20.04.1 and at the same time I switched to the Brave Browser. As I was frequently experiencing my system freezing, and by freezing I mean I could still move the mouse cursor but nothing would respond, I assumed the issue was the Brave Browser and I found on their git a history of a similar issue. I disabled hardware acceleration in Brave, which is a reported workaround, but when that did not help I switched back to Chrome.

Unfortunately even using the latest version of Chrome, the issue is ongoing. When the system becomes unresponsive it stays so for approximately 30 seconds to 1 minute. A few times I have had to use REISUB or when that did not work cold reboot, but the majority of the time it just starts responding again. I have tried to completely mirror the same clean install setup and packages on my Dell XPS 13 9360, which does not experience the same issue.

As I post this morning some of the lockups I have experienced today have allowed me to switch window, for instance terminal would freeze but I could switch to a non-responsive Chrome or vice versa.

Please find several logs below which were created after the issue occurred and immediately after my system started responding again. Often I am not doing anything especially heavy, just Chrome open with 4 or 5 tabs. My system is an i5-4690K, GTX 970, 8GB of RAM, Samsung SSD 840 EVO Basic SATA. I am using the Nvidia driver 450.66.

Searching for a similar error to one of those that occurred a lot this morning:  `06:13:58 fuser: Cannot stat file /proc/2733/fd/1023: Permission denied` (the path after /proc/ varies) I found this thread [Getting strange errors while downloading mysql](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129029/getting-strange-errors-while-downloading-mysql) and although I was not installing MySQL and I do not have it installed but in case it could help I followed some of the troubleshooting steps: libaio1 was installed but I input `sudo apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev`, `sudo apt install aptitude`, `sudo aptitude update`, `sudo aptitude upgrade`, and rebooted. Unfortunately the same issue occurs, and as you will see from the latter 4 logs this happened as many times over 34 minutes, and those are just the ones I generated logs for and the count is more like twice that. Since rebooting about 30 minutes ago it has only happened twice so far but I expect it to continue throughout the day as normal.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/T8mfWwsyHS/

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hKNtVqdkbz/

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dCBjJqJRzs/

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vM8X6TbCC6/

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WnmRmX65c8/

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jnhGPFgNpX/

Could you please review my logs and let me know if there is something that may suggest how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have experienced issues like this and here are the things I have done.
Start by checking if any app is running in the startup.Since ubuntu has some Bloat-wares I would recommend you to check anything that is not a system file running in the background and stopping it.

After that cold boot the system and go to the update setting and check all official sources and go to updates and check everything there.

Again do a `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt upgrade` again `sudo apt update`.

There were few times when my extensions were not installed properly and was facing the issues of hang. So keep in mind for that.

If nothing works then try switching to pop os since it's an ubuntu based system with minimalist apps pre-loaded it's less likely you will face any issues.