# Failure to install MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, dpkg, mysql

I'm at the state of frustration trying to install MySQL 8.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04 box.  I have searched and see many answers (and also a lot of posts about failures) but nothing is working.

I start by the following:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

And then this:

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

On checking my apt package I see a new file created, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`, **but the content can't possibly be right for 8.0!** - content here:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
# deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
# deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
```

Anyway, next step is this:

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

This give me a UI which looks correct:

[image: first step of dpkg]

Leading to this selection:

[image: second step of dpkg]

When I select OK on THIS option, I am sent back to the first screenshot.  Then that takes me to the 2nd.  I am now in an infinite loop.  When I hit escape, I get the following message:

```
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
```

At this point, I don't know what further steps to take.  My thoughts are, is there any way to install MySQL 8.0 directly without apt-get?  I am appreciative of any and all solutions here, thanks.

Comment: Select OK option (4th one) and then select OK (the one in the Middleton and bottom) in the first screen.

Comment: No combination of choices escapes the loop - only way out was to install 5.7 which I didn't want to do.

Comment: The config and UI issue seems like a bug. Please file a bug report with the MySQL developers who developed that config package you downloaded.

Comment: As many times as I'm running through things and documenting them, I'll be able to catch it on my next server and file the report.  Thanks @user535733 for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I am leaving this question, even though the solution was found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122608/how-to-upgrade-to-mysql-8-0), as this was a clean install of 8.0 vs. an upgrade from 5.7.  I note again that that `.deb` package was definitely putting 5.7 pieces in, and not 8.0.  Here is the actual contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` that worked:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
```

a quick `apt update` and then `apt install mysql-server` and I had 8.0 successfully installed.