# Can't install mysql-server with 'sudo apt install mysql-server'

Tags: apt, mysql, dependencies

i'm new in **linux** and i got a problem: can't install mysql after **downloading** `mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb` from [mysql official page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) and configuring it using:

`sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb` i got:

```
(Reading database ... 360760 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.17-1) over (0.8.17-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.17-1) ...
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
OK
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config` i got:

```
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
OK
```

---

and when **typing** `sudo apt install mysql-server` i got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.24-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I was looking on **internet** the way to fix this, but i can't find the solution.

I'm using ***Linux Mint***

---

### Updates:

> run the command lsb_release -cs to print your version.

[image: lsb_release -cs]

> However, you should be using apt to install instead of dpkg like this sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb

using: `sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb`

```
[sudo] password for dev:     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-apt-config' instead of './mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb'
mysql-apt-config is already the newest version (0.8.17-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Questions about linux mint are off topic here on Askubuntu but you can ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com instead where it is on topic. However, you should be using apt to install instead of dpkg like this `sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb` but in any case, [your answer can be found here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122890/167115). Since you aren't using Ubuntu, I'm not sure how to proceed. Probably just insert the Ubuntu version name equivalent to your version of Linux mint in place of bionic (e.g., groovy, focal, etc.).

Comment: Yes, I just checked and it looks like Linux Mint uses the same release names as Ubuntu. If you aren't sure what version name to use, run the command `lsb_release -cs` to print your version.

Comment: I updated the question. Please help:(

Comment: [Your version is focal](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/sources.html). See [the answer I linked](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122890/167115) but use `focal` instead of `bionic` when following the instructions.

Comment: Or, you could copy and paste into the file with the 'bionic' as is in the instructions and then use the following `sed` command to fix the file instead of the `sed` command used in the answer: `sudo sed -i 's/bionic/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`

Answer (score 4):

mysql repository is misconfigured because the used codename is `xenial` instead of `focal`. Use the following command to fix mysql repository (Ulyssa is based on Focal):

```
sudo sed -i 's/xenial/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```